# How do I use PowerMock / Mockito / EasyMock to use a mocked object for dependency injection?

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking

I have an `AuthenticationManager.authenticate(username,password)` method that gets called in someMethod of a SomeService under test. The AuthenticationManager is injected into SomeService:

```
@Component
public class SomeService {
    @Inject
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public void someMethod() {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(username, password);
        // do more stuff that I want to test
    }
}
```

Now for the unit test I need the authenticate method to just pretend it worked correctly, in my case do nothing, so I can test if the method itself does the expected work (Authentication is tested elsewhere according to the unit testing principles, however authenticate needs to be called inside that method)

So I am thinking, I need `SomeService` to use a mocked `AuthenticationManager` that will just return and do nothing else when `authenticate()` gets called by `someMethod()`. How do I do that with PowerMock (or EasyMock / Mockito, which are part of PowerMock)?

Or is there another way to tell Spring to use some Mock instead of the real deal, when injeeting the `AuthenticationManager` into `SomeService`?

Or is my design wrong?

Thanks!

---

**Edit - found a solution, would like to hear comments**

So I found a nice way to inject a mock without having to use a setter or package level:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class TestOrderService {

    @Mock
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @InjectMocks 
    private OrderService orderService = new OrderService();

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        Mockito.doNothing().when(this.authenticationManager).authenticate(null, null);
    }

    @Test
    public void testOrderService() {
        orderService.save(null, null, null);
    }
}
```

with OrderService like this:

```
public void save(String username, Order order) {
    authenticationManager.authenticate(username, password);
    // do something with the order...
}
```

Now the save method will call authenticate on the mock and the mock does nothing leaving me free to test the actual work inside my service method (which actually is calling a manager method but that was not the point ;) )

Answer (score 2):

I personally don't use spring on the unit testing side (except maybe a single test to verify that the application context loads properly). Instead I use setter methods to manually wire the mocks (actually I use project lombok's `@Setter` annotation), OR if I'm using `@Autowired` I make the member variables package scoped so the unit test can directly set the values.

I don't see how you're going to get things like Mockito to work via dependency injection, because you'll always be new-ing your object inside the unit test and then creating mock behaviors for the methods. Also, you don't lose much by doing it this way, because you'll only need to setup direct dependencies of the class under test (because they're mocks), which is much easier than what spring DI does, which is recursive dependency creation and wiring on real objects.

Comment: Good point actually. Was wondering if I couldn't reduce the testing time by removing the spring context from the equation... How about using reflections to access the private beans? Or maybe there's a frameworks that wraps this behaviour?
 I don't feel comfortable creating a security risk by making the beans package scope and I don't like to add setters just so I can unit test a class when I don't need them otherwise...

Comment: That's why I like Lombok. You add an annotation and it generates the setter method. The setter method is still there but I don't have to look at it every time I edit the file so it's much less annoying

Comment: Found a nice solution without a setter or spring context. Would like to hear your opinion.

Comment: Nice I hadn't seen `@InjectMocks` before. I'm going to start using that instead...